# C code lines doing nothing

Tags: c

I am currently experiencing some strange behaviour in my C code. I want to use Gaussian elimination with a Matrix that is used as a struct like

```
typedef struct {
  int nrows;
  int ncols;
  double **row;
} Matrix;
```

The only problem I am having is when using this code lines to solve a step of gaussian elimination:

```
A->row[zeile][0] = A->row[zeile][0] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][0];
A->row[zeile][1] = A->row[zeile][1] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][1];
A->row[zeile][2] = A->row[zeile][2] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][2];
```

It didn't work with a for loop, so I have written Step 1 of my algorithm as single commands. When running the code as above only the first line of my code changes elements of my matrix. Line 2 and 3 don't change any values.
When commenting out line 1 and running my program again, step 2 and step 3 change my matrix elements as intended.

I don't really understand this strange behaviour of my program. I hopy, someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve].

Comment: `A->row[zeile][1] = A->row[zeile][1] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][1];` uses the updated value of `A->row[zeile][0]` rather than the original one.  Is this code's true intent?

Comment: Thank you, chux. I think I'm being kind of blind here. I overlooked, that I used the updated value. Changed it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

[Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) requires updates based on the *original set* of values.

```
A->row[zeile][0] = A->row[zeile][0] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][0];
//                                        not original values
//                                        v                   v                   v
A->row[zeile][1] = A->row[zeile][1] - (A->row[zeile][0] / A->row[0][0]) * A->row[0][1];
```

Instead, *something* like

```
// Save some of the original values
double A_0_0 = A->row[0][0];
double A_0[3] = { A->row[0][0], A->row[0][1], A->row[0][2] };

for (zeile = 0; zeile < 3; zeile++) 
  double A_zeile_0 = A->row[zeile][0];
  for (c = 0; c < C; c++) 
    A->row[zeile][c] -= (A_zeile_0 / A_0_0) * A_0[c];
```

Comment: was my first thought: "..original set of values..."

Comment: @slashmais Unclear why you [hate magic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15161/slashmais)[Ð](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth)

Comment: 'magic' use here refers mainly to relying on side-effects in code / things happening without explicitly coding it, simple example: I always add `close` when I use std::i- or ostream, I have a built-in mistrust of smart-pointers, and await with trepidation the incoming `operator .()`. this last one is going to cause much trouble, I think :-) PS: the 'eth' means ..?

Comment: @slashmais I'd expect "..--.." for `?`, not "..--.".   Perhaps a different convention.